# What rest API can be used to get default values of fields for create issue?

Tags: rest, web-services, jira

I am using jira rest api's in my application.
I have found the api for getting the meta-data for creating jira issue but that API doesn't return default values of the fields for example :-

This is the request :-

```
http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/latest/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=QA&issuetypeNames=Bug&expand=project.issuetypes.fields
```

the default value of priority field is set to "major" and the description of priority is also customized but the return from api is:-

```
{
    "expand": "projects",
    "projects": [
        {
            "expand": "issuetypes",
            "self": "http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/project/QA",
            "id": "10010",
            "key": "QA",
            "name": "QA",
            "avatarUrls": {
                "16x16": "http://kelpie9:8081/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10010&avatarId=10011",
                "48x48": "http://kelpie9:8081/secure/projectavatar?pid=10010&avatarId=10011"
            },
            "issuetypes": [
                {
                    "expand": "fields",
                    "self": "http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issuetype/1",
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Bug",
                    "iconUrl": "http://kelpie9:8081/images/icons/bug.gif",
                    "fields": {
                        "summary": {
                            "required": true,
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "system": "summary"
                            },
                            "operations": [
                                "set"
                            ]
                        },
                        "timetracking": {
                            "required": false,
                            "operations": [ ]
                        },
                        "issuetype": {
                            "required": true,
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "issuetype",
                                "system": "issuetype"
                            },
                            "operations": [ ],
                            "allowedValues": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1",
                                    "name": "Bug",
                                    "description": "A problem which impairs or prevents the functions of the product.",
                                    "iconUrl": "http://kelpie9:8081/images/icons/bug.gif"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "priority": {
                            "required": false,
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "priority",
                                "system": "priority"
                            },
                            "name": "Priority",
                            "operations": [
                                "set"
                            ],
                            "allowedValues": [
                                {
                                    "self": "http://172.19.30.101:18080/rest/api/2/priority/1",
                                    "iconUrl": "http://172.19.30.101:18080/images/icons/priority_blocker.gif",
                                    "name": "Blocker",
                                    "id": "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "self": "http://172.19.30.101:18080/rest/api/2/priority/2",
                                    "iconUrl": "http://172.19.30.101:18080/images/icons/priority_critical.gif",
                                    "name": "Critical",
                                    "id": "2"
                                },
                                {
                                    "self": "http://172.19.30.101:18080/rest/api/2/priority/3",
                                    "iconUrl": "http://172.19.30.101:18080/images/icons/priority_major.gif",
                                    "name": "Major",
                                    "id": "3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "self": "http://172.19.30.101:18080/rest/api/2/priority/4",
                                    "iconUrl": "http://172.19.30.101:18080/images/icons/priority_minor.gif",
                                    "name": "Minor",
                                    "id": "4"
                                },
                                {
                                    "self": "http://172.19.30.101:18080/rest/api/2/priority/5",
                                    "iconUrl": "http://172.19.30.101:18080/images/icons/priority_trivial.gif",
                                    "name": "Trivial",
                                    "id": "5"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "customfield_10080": {
                            "required": false,
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": "string",
                                "custom": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:labels",
                                "customId": 10080
                            },
                            "operations": [ ]
                        },

                        "customfield_10010": {
                            "required": false,
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": "string",
                                "custom": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:labels",
                                "customId": 10010
                            },
                            "operations": [ ]
                        },
                        "customfield_10071": {
                            "required": false,
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": "string",
                                "custom": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:textfield",
                                "customId": 10071
                            },
                            "operations": [ ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There is nothing like default value or description in priority field, how will I get those values?

Comment: I'm surprised that the default values are not retrievable from the JIRA REST API documented at http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/ Worth filing a request for this at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA
I searched and didn't find an existing issue related to this.

Comment: Am surprised too, thanks for the response buddy..